# generate a whole number between 1-100

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is supposed to generate a whole number between 1-100, and I believe the code is correct for it, however if the user tries to guess the computerChoice, it seems like it generates a decimal number, which wrecks the game.

question: Do I need to adjust the way I write this to make it work within my code?

http://codepen.io/dpcarlson/pen/zmKGD

```
var computerChoice = Math.floor((Math.random()*100) + 1);
```

Comment: How would that generate a decimal?

Comment: Fixed by using `userChoice == computerChoice` instead of `===`. Apparently, types aren't matching. `computerChoice` is a number, I didn't look to see where `userChoice` is coming from, but it's a string.

Comment: `userChoice = parseInt($(this).text(),10);`

Comment: you might need to close the question yourself :)

Comment: When you are reading `textContent` from the DOM, it will be a string. What you generate is a number. So when you do `===` on them, which also checks whether they are the same type, it obviously fails. Tip: learn to use the console/debugger in your browser (all modern ones have one), without that you are simply lost and cannot find even the simplest bugs like this.

Comment: Please put the rest of your code in the question for future use and reference.

Answer (score 0):

userChoice is string and computerChoice is number.

```
userChoice = parseInt($(this).text(),10);
```

Comment: Never use `parseInt` like this. Always specify the second parameter. Also, there is no `int` type in Javascript.

Comment: @kapa don't really understand why never use parseInt like so? the second parameter is just ***radix***, if we just care about decimal radix, it's `10` by default so we don't need to pass `10` as the second parameter.

Comment: looks like it's the reason of supporting the old versions of browsers whereas the default radix is `8`. Not sure how old those versions are.

Comment: @KingKing [You can find details here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) The default radix is never 8, but in some implementations, if you do not specify radix, and the number starts with `0`, 8 will be assumed instead of 10 as a radix. This leads to bugs that are difficult to track down.

Comment: @kapa yes, that's the case I meant, the default radix is just 8 (in some old browsers) in case the input string starts with `0`.

Comment: @KingKing IE8 certainly makes this mistake, and I don't know about older Android browsers. Modern browsers use 10 as a default. Still, it is easier and safer to just include the second parameter. It does not cause any problems, but it can save your ass in some circumstances :). Note: removed my downvote.

Comment: Yes, if it starts with 0, it is treated as octal. Javascript strict mode changes this behaviour to default to 16 if it starts with "0x", otherwise it's always 10, but obviously you shouldn't trust that all browsers respect this. Always set the radix param. I've made this mistake in date validation code, which somehow stopped working in August.:)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are doing a numerical comparison (and not an alphabetical comparison) by converting the userChoice string into an integer:

```
userChoice = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
```